# Is there an English locale with SI units?

Tags: localization, android-wear

I hate using devices in my native language, so I normally use the US locale. However, I also want to have Celcius, meters, kilograms and sane date formatting :)

I have a Wear watch and it uses the phone's locale to know what units to use. This means I get Fahrenheit weather and mile distances.

Is there a locale setting I can use to get SI units but retain English?

Comment: Have you tried setting it to Canadian or Australian english?

Comment: @zdan Canada did the trick! I'll probably have to suffer through some weird spellings, but Australian English likely has more. If you add that as an answer, perhaps with a link to https://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/en_CA/, I will accept it as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the locale to Canadian english [(en_CA) which sets its units to metric](https://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/en_CA/). Things like dates and currency are fairly compatible with the US.

You could always set the dictionary for spell check to US english under Languages & Input in settings. Though, as you point out in your comment, you may have to deal with some "misspellings" in some menus and messages. It will add some *colour* to your android experience.